# Backlight control configuration misbehaves on an Ideapad.

Tags: linux-kernel, grub, backlight

I did a clean Ubuntu install on a Lenovo Ideapad P500.

The backlight started okay, but after pressing the keyboard light function once, it got reset to a very dark state.  The brightness setting wasn't adjustable then, even after restarting the system.

I found a partial fix that involved changing a setting in `/etc/default/grub`; specifically, I added `acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor` in the variable `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`.

But this is only a partial fix because it selects a zero-brightness level at startup, and it also turns the brightness off when selecting the max level.  This is an annoyance.

I discovered that this behavior is independent of Ubuntu, since something similar happened when I installed OpenSUSE in dual boot;  and I also found similar posts that were related to different Lenovo laptops.  My question is if this has to do with the Linux kernel, and/or if I have to update the drivers?  If so, how can I fix this?

Let me know if I can provide more details to fix this.  Thanks for helping out.